# How do I prevent Angular from loading a Component twice?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My Angular app is loading a component twice. Initially, I had `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my component's template and it was working fine but was still giving me these errors:

```
core.umd.js:3257 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'
core.umd.js:3262 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
core.umd.js:3263 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'(…) Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent' 
zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'
```

To resolve these errors, I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to my template. But now my app is loading my component twice.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id
  selector:'body', 
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Doctor Application';
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Do you have something like a `main.ts` file where you bootstrap the module?

Comment: Yes, I do have main.ts @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AppComponent` shouldn't be part of the routing. It's used to bootstrap. That's what the error is about. You're trying to add the `AppComponent` to the routing, but there's no `<router-outlet>` for it, because it is the top-level component.

Comment: I removed it .. and this is error ... core.umd.js:3257 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''

Comment: Add a route `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'otherRoute', pathMatch: 'full' }`. You should redirect to the path you want to go to first. Otherwise if you have no other routes configured, remove the routing.

Comment: But i don't have any other route yet @peeskillet .... that's why it still give me error .... but application is working fine

Comment: Then remove the routing (`<router-outlet>` and `RouterModule`) until you have some.

Answer (score 1):

The app-component is load and is not necessary declare in the AppRoutingModule
, if you add AppComponent in your Routing module he its load twice:
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component'; **<- Remove this line **

const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: '',
     component: AppComponent **<-Remove this line**
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```